# Exchange scripts remote execution - Exchange & Generic PS Cmdlets

Tags: c#, exchange-server, powershell-2.0

Am trying to execute a powershell script file against a remote exchange server. Script file contains a couple of exchange cmdlets, and some write-host statements and custom object definitions.

Code ::

```
        SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();
        foreach (char x in Password)
            securePassword.AppendChar(x);
        PSCredential credentials = new PSCredential(UserID, securePassword);
        var connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("http://   exchangeserver:5985/wsman"), 
              "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell", credentials);
        connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = script.AuthenticationMode;
        powerShellEngine.Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(host, connectionInfo);
        powerShellEngine.Runspace.Open();
        powerShellEngine.AddScript("Content of PS1 file goes here");

        //Some parameter addition goes here..

        var results = powerShellEngine.Invoke();
```

Following options I have tried so far:

**Connect to Endpoint: exchangeserver:5985 / wsman**

- Exchange cmdlets not available when connecting to the above endpoint. Tried to connect to exchange server and import session as first line in my script file:

  $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://  EXCHANGESERVER  / PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos

  Import-PSSession $Session

  This resulted in below error:

  The following error occurred while using Kerberos authentication: A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.

  Is this due to a Kerberos double hop issue? This code is executed from a console app..
- Tried importing PS Snapin using the Add - PSSNapin cmdlet as the first line in the script. This failed.
- Tried executing the exchange ps1 script as the exchange shell does..

  . `C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1'; Connect-ExchangeServer exchangeserver`

  No response.. Code hangs for a lot of time.

**Connect to Endpoint: exchangeserver/Powershell**

- Only exchange cmdlets are executable. Powershell virtual directory locks down access to all generic PS cmdlets.

Could someone throw any possible workarounds?

Note: Its fine to bypass the RBAC check, since this will be executed by an admin account. Can we load exchange cmdlets to normal PS session without connecting to exchange server?